# Need help making an even slope. I'm new

Tags: vertices

[image]

I'm looking to take the 4 vertices circled in red and raise them along the Z axis to create a slope with the same X axis coordinates as the slope with the green line such that all 5 faces create one smooth plane. I've been messing around trying to figure it out myself and I've tried searching for a solution but I couldn't find anything, or at least nothing that I could understand

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you want to do. If you want to have all the verts at one specific x coordinate you could copy the x value of one vert to the other in the properties panel.

Answer (score 2):

With *Pivot Center* set to 'Active'..

- in Edit>Face mode, select the face you want to flatten to
- hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to create a Custom Transform Orientation from the face. (Check 'Use After Creation' and, if you don't want your custom orientations to hang around in a list: 'Overwrite Previous')
- in Edit>Edge mode, select the edge-loop around the hole
- in Edit>Vertex mode (the hole edge-loop should still be selected, as vertices), also make one of the vertices on the orientation-face active, by <kbd>Shift</kbd>-selecting it last.
- hit <kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>, to scale the all your selected vertices to 0 along the normal (the local Z-axis) of the face defining your custom orientation, centered on the active vertex.